# Impersonation in ASP.NET web.page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, epplus, impersonation

I have a webpage in a huge ASP.NET web application that is supposed to update excel files (using EPPlus) located in a local computer on a button click.

It works fine on localhost but results in this error on the server.

**System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.**

Writing permissions cannot be granted to IIS account - NETWORKSERVICE for now.

Is there any other way besides impersonation to fix this error (the users have 'write' permissions for the path, so doing this would solve the error)?

And if impersonation is the only way, can it be done for just this particular webpage? (I don't want to significantly change settings of either IIS or web application to solve this problem)

Comment: According to the error message, please make your IIS APP pool identity have full control of related folders. I think authorizing the IIS account is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few questions that need to be answered:

- Are you impersonating the current logged in user
- Do you want to access the files regardless of who is logged in?

**For the first one**

- You can use the following code to impersonate the current logged in
  windows user

using System.Security.Principal;
using(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate())
{
//your code goes here
}

**For the second one**

- You can run IIS under a specific user that has access to that
  location.
- You can use an impersonation class , a few of those are
  available on the net, e.g [Simple Impersonation Library](https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/SimpleImpersonation) can help
  you to simplify impersonating a specific user
- There is a great post, and C# class that can be used from https://daoudisamir.com/impersonate-users-in-c/
- If you are self hosting the site, then you can create a windows user that has access to the resource and you can login as that user under a using statement and access the resource